# How to extract all information by using id

Tags: machine-learning, python, clustering, jupyter

I need to apply classifier algorithm after clustering. Now after clustering I find the id numbers that which id belongs which cluster. I clustered them into 2 cluster.

Now I need to collect those data by using those id. But I don't know how I can collect all information by using those id.

As I use jupyeter notebook and in main data I have no attribute named id and those id assigned jupyter notebook when I load data from main data file.

This is my main data

[image]

Here is my code to find which data belongs which cluster.

```
x = 0.10
i=0
C_i = np.where(labels == i)[0].tolist()
n_i = len(C_i) # number of points in cluster i

# (2) indices of the points from X to be sampled from cluster i
sample_i = np.random.choice(C_i, int(x * n_i)) 
print (i, sample_i)
```

and after clustering I find these ids

[image]

New addition:

suppose my loading file name is train.
now using `train.loc[26]` command I get the info of that specific id.

[image]

But I need to collect all info into a new data frame like as `train` dataframe

Comment: Is there a problem left?

Comment: No. I already solved that problem and I also added the solution of my problem.

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

To create a list by using those index number like. Suppose I need 10% data's index number. At first I collect 0 (where i=0) number cluster's index numbers then 1(where i=1) number cluster index numbers

`x = 0.10
 i=0
 C_i = np.where(labels == i)[0].tolist() 
 n_i = len(C_i)
 #indices of the points from X to be sampled from cluster i
 sample_i = np.random.choice(C_i, int(x * n_i))
 print (i, sample_i)
 list1=(sample_i)`

`x = 0.10
 i=1
 C_i = np.where(labels == i)[0].tolist() 
 n_i = len(C_i)
 # indices of the points from X to be sampled from cluster i
 sample_i = np.random.choice(C_i, int(x * n_i))
 print (i, sample_i)
 list2=(sample_i)`

[image]

After found two list for 2 cluster I merge those two list into 1 list

`new_list = np.concatenate((list1,list2))
new_train_data=train.loc[new_list]
new_train_data.head()`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Define a new column, then use these ids to select the relevant rows and set that column to the appropriate id:

```
from pandas import DataFrame,Series
from numpy.random import rand
df = DataFrame(rand(10,10)).assign(cluster=0)
clusters = Series([[1,3,5],[0,2,4,6,7,8,9]])
for cluster,rows in clusters.iteritems():
    df.loc[rows]["cluster"] = cluster
```

Now you can do your `groupby`s on column "cluster".